# Why is transfinite recursion needed for the construction of Borel sets?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

I'm reading the Hrbaceck and Jech's book and they say that recursion until $\omega$ does not work for constructing the Borel sets

[image]

But I haven't been able to find such sequences, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you prove $\Sigma^0_{n+1} \ne \Sigma^0_n$ ?  If so, choose $B_n \in \Sigma^0_{n+1} \setminus \Sigma^0_n$ on disjoint intervals $(n,n+1)$.  The union is not in any $\Sigma^0_n$.